# How to open deep link inside iframe on iOS by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, iframe

I tried to use a deep link inside an `iframe` on iOS.
It works well if the app is already installed, but if it is not installed yet it does not do anything.

```
$(".test-app").click(function () {
    window.top.location.href = "myapp://......";
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.top.location.href = "https://......";
    });
})
```

It looks like the `window.top.location.href = "https://......";`  does not work.

How to use deep link inside `iframe` on iOS correctly?

Note: if I do not use it in `iframe` it works fine.

Comment: hey @tilo, how did you fix it?